# Fail to close IE process by user32.dll function call

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, process

I follow [this ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420023/refresh-browsers-page-programmatically-from-a-net-winforms-application) and open a process like this,

```
// open IE (ok)
Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("IEXPLORE.EXE", "www.google.com");
IntPtr handle = process.Handle;

// refresh it (ok)
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

ShowWindow(handle, 1);
SendKeys.SendWait("{F5}");

// however, fail to close it ( NOT ok)
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool CloseWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

CloseWindow(handle); // don't work
```

no error, no exception occurs. I've checked MSDN about [CLoseWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632678%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but still got failed. Any idea about it ? Thanks !

**update:**
okay, I fixed it and made it more robust.
to call this process's CloseMainWindow() function works

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

bool bOk = ShowWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, 1);
if (bOk) {
    bOk = SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
    if (bOk){
        process.CloseMainWindow();
    }
}
```

Comment: ShowWindow() returns bool.  *Never* ignore winapi return values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for answering my own question. actually I can't find the answer without @fejesjoco's reminding. I really appreciate.

the answer is to call this process's CloseMainWindow() function, like this

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

bool bOk = ShowWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, 1);
if (bOk) {
    bOk = SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
    if (bOk){
        process.CloseMainWindow();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Process.Handle is a process handle, not a window handle, so window commands won't work on it. Try using the Process.MainWindowHandle property. Note that this whole thing may not work if IE spawns additional processes or opens additional windows.

Comment: if I can make sure it's IE's process and get its window handle, does that mean there isn't any additional process's handle that I might get ? and I tried to get MainWindowHandle instead of handle property, it works better now. thx.