# Refresh a web page programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I would like to know if it is possible to refresh a web page from a click of a button from a winform app.

I have a form that when a press a button starts a process and shows a web page in a browser windows and I want to refresh it when I press another button instead of opening another windows.

Is it possible?

I've checked this question [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10420455/3060735) but thus it refresh the file I already call?

I launch the webpage like this:

```
string path = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                       .Parent.FullName; 
string target = @"DashBoard.html"; 
string finalPath = Path.Combine(path, target); 
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(finalPath);
```

I have checked one of the solutions in that question and i understand it but what i can't find is if there is a way that it will work with all browsers.

Any hint?

Comment: The link you've provided would allow the server to signal the client to refresh.  You seem to want to just launch a web browser from the client then send it a refresh.  Is that correct?

Comment: How are you opening the browser window?

Comment: That question appears to have a decent answer. Something better might be able to be worked out depending on your environment. Do you control which web browser is launched to view the web page? I.e., is it always launching Internet Explorer, or might it be launched in Chrome/Firefox/whatever the user's default browser is?

Comment: @paqogomez you are correct, that is what i want.

Comment: @DaveBish i'm doing it like this 
string path = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName;
            string target = @"DashBoard.html";
            string finalPath = Path.Combine(path, target);

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(finalPath);

Comment: @CharlieKilian if i'm not wrong it launches it to the default web browser, in my case is chrome

Comment: Have you considered putting the Refresh button on the web page instead of in the WinForms application? If that option is available it would certainly be easier, and a lot more robust.

Comment: what i was thinking was creating 2 buttons, one for updating the info and another to visualize the info selected previously. for example the user wants to see it so ihe press the visualize button and after that he wants to add more data so he press the update button. now when i press the update button it will open a new window. if possible i would like to if the windows was already presented just refresh it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution, this is the function i've created

```
private void RefreshPage()
{
    int count = 0;
    IntPtr[] explorerHandle = new IntPtr[4] { 
        FindWindow(null, "DashBoard - Google Chrome"), 
        FindWindow(null, "DashBoard - Internet Explorer"),
        FindWindow(null, "DashBoard - Opera"), 
        FindWindow(null, "DashBoard - Firefox")
    };

    foreach (IntPtr value in explorerHandle)
    {
        if (value != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            count++;
            SetForegroundWindow(value);
            SendKeys.Send("{F5}");
        }
    }
    if(count == 0)
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://localhost:9000/DashBoard.html");
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bad idea, and you should look at trying to have the webpage refresh itself somehow.

Alternatively - you could look into the Chrome API - (assuming you only wish to target chrome?)

http://dev.chromium.org/developers

As a last resort - you could always kill the existing browser process - and open a new one:

```
var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(finalPath);

//When refresh wanted:
process.Close();
//open again
var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(finalPath);
```

Comment: but i cannot restrict myself to use only chrome